# No suitable constructor google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm trying to insert data in my google datastore, so I send this request throught google API explorer:

```
    POST https://local-sport-meeting-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/localSportMeetingApi/v1/rencontre

Content-Type:  application/json
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "date": {
  "day": 30,
  "hour": 20,
  "minute": 15,
  "month": 11,
  "year": 2014
 },
 "idComp": "5153049148391424",
 "idParticipant2": "5664902681198592",
 "idPartiticpant1": "5734055144325120",
 "latitude": 3.105024,
 "lieu": "STADE MARCEL MICHELIN\"",
 "longitude": 45.789907
}
```

but this is returning this error:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.iutclermont.lpmobile.localsportmeeting.backend.DatePerso]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.iutclermont.lpmobile.localsportmeeting.backend.Rencontre[\"date\"])"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.iutclermont.lpmobile.localsportmeeting.backend.DatePerso]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.iutclermont.lpmobile.localsportmeeting.backend.Rencontre[\"date\"])"
 }
}
```

I generate my entity with Objectify and an app engine module in android studio and I have an empty constructor as requested by Objectify

Do anyone already have this problem or know how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here... Did you find a solution?

Comment: ertainly did, as it was for a scholarly project and I finished it. But unfortunately, I would be unable to tell you how... It's been a year I encountered this problem. BTW, I may still have the source, so I'll look if I can find an answer. But can't guarantee it